# Ansible Module Development argument_spec Specification

Tags: ansible

While reading the [Ansible Module Development](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html), I did not see any references to what the `argument_spec` specification should be. I figured I would look into the code base and see if the argument_spec would be documented, but the [GitHub ansible/ansible basic.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L740-L755) file doesn't have much in the way of a argument specification. What should be in there? The closest I can find is where an older document shows this bit of code from the [Ansible 2.3 Dev Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html)

```
module = AnsibleModule(
   argument_spec = dict(
       state     = dict(default='present', choices=['present', 'absent']),
       name      = dict(required=True),
       enabled   = dict(required=True, type='bool'),
       something = dict(aliases=['whatever'])
   )
)
```

Would I be correct in assuming that the full argument_spec specification is

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec = {
        default  = 'default_value',
        type     = 'str',
        required = True,
        aliases  = ['dv', 'value'],
        choices  = ['default_value', 'strings', 'test']
    }
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is more or less complete description of argument spec in the documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec.

At the time of writing available fields are: `type`, `elements`, `default`, `fallback`, `choices`, `required`, `no_log`, `aliases`, `options`, `apply_defaults`, `removed_in_version`.